# How to delay KDE desktop session restore

Tags: login, kde, session

How can I specify a delay for the Desktop Session restoration after login?

The reason I need that is that I use [Plasma Global Application Menu](http://fasterland.net/activate-global-menu-kde-plasma-5-9.html) and session restoration after login. And it seems that [the session is being restored before the menu service is ready](https://blog.broulik.de/2018/03/gtk-global-menu/#comment-10163), resulting in restored applications' menus not being processed. Specifically, I constantly have Dolphin open with several tabs which restores after login, and every time without the menu, so that when I need the menu I end up closing Dolphin and reopening it and all the tabs manually.

While this seems like a bug, it could take years to get fixed. And a workaround delaying session restore seems logical, just like there is possibility delaying startup applications wrapping a command with `sleep 10s && app &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though a way to delay session restore hasn't been found, the issue with Plasma Global Application Menu is fixed in Plasma 5.15 so that it initializes before the session restore happens.